# 'Keyword not supported error' Using Dot Connect and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, database, dotconnect

I am trying to connect a MySQL database to a winform using C#. I am receiving this error: System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'host'. I have already checked that the database has a proper connection using the test connection and the connection string that I am using is the one provided to me using the server explorer. After doing research, the issue lies in either the references I'm using or in the app.config itself. Does anyone have any experience with this issue or can offer any feedback? Here is the very basic code snippet i'm working with:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace savetodatabasepractice
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = "User Id=XXXXXX;Host=localhost;Database=XXXXXX";
                SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_newdata (ID, Temperature, Humidity) VALUES (1, 72, 34)", conn);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017, DotConnect for MySQL, MySQL server, and Wamp Connect. Thank you!

EDIT: After reading documentation a sample c# program with this format should look like

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Devart.Data.MySql;

namespace savetodatabasepractice
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("User Id=root;Host=localhost;Database=XXXXXX;");
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_newdata (ID, Temperature, Humidity) VALUES (1,73,32)";
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                int aff = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show(aff + " rows were affected.");
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error encountered during INSERT operation.");
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The key is to not only use the correct reference but to also download the correct package on nuget. Easy to forget for beginners!

Comment: try `server` instead of `host`

Answer (score 0):

***What???*** you are using `DotConnect for MySQL` but you use a `SqlConnection` class. That's the issue here cause `SqlConnection` is for SQLServer. You should use `using Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection` instead.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
```

Check the documentation first which says everything. https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/

Comment: Classic case of not reading the manual! After reading the documentation, the correct reference is `using Devart.Data.MySql;`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and I'll update my question with correct code in case anyone else has the same problem as me.